# Python Selenium: Scrolling not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate [this](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/marketing/) Instagram link. I need to scroll and scroll and fetch all links. I am trying following but not working.

```
def fetch_links_by_hashtag(hash_tag):
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/marketing/'
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    is_more = False

    try:
        elem_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Load more")))
        elem_more.click()
        is_more = True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))

    pop = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('footer')
    #pop = driver.find_element_by_link_text('About us')
    # pop = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_4gt3b')
    if pop is not None:
        for i in range(10):
            print('Calling scrolling script')
            # It scolls till end
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', pop)
            sleep(4)
        html = pop.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

[How to scroll down to the bottom of a page ?](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 宏杰李 answer

`driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element_obj)`

Also, if you want to make an extra scroll:

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].parentNode.scrollTop = "
                      "arguments[0].parentNode.scrollTop + {extra_scroll}"
                      .format(extra_scroll=extra_scroll_pixels), element_obj)
```

My entire code:

```
def _scroll_to_element(driver, element,
                       extra_scroll=None):
    # Scroll to element
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

    # Scroll parentNode with the extra pixels (If provided)
    if extra_scroll:
        driver.execute_script(
            "return arguments[0].parentNode.scrollTop = "
            "arguments[0].parentNode.scrollTop + {extra_scroll}".format(
                extra_scroll=str(extra_scroll)), element)
```

Comment: His it different than what I did? also what is `element_obj`?

Comment: @Volatil3 It's a bit different; 1. see the `return` (might make a different) 2. I'm calling `parentNode` 3. `element_obj` is what you called `pop` (The element you want to scroll to). See the method that I use (Never had any problems)